# Sql types and encrypted size

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, encryption-symmetric

I am introducing Symmetric Key encription on some dynamically generated Sql Server 2012 tables.

I expect to store:

1. varchar(X)
2. integers
3. date time
4. boolean

I create the key using

```
CREATE SYMMETRIC KEY MyKey
    WITH ALGORITHM = AES_256
    ENCRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE MyCertificate
GO
```

I insert data using i.e.

```
insert into SecureTable(value) values (EncryptByKey(@ui, CONVERT(varbinary(max), 12345)))
```

The result is something like:

> 0x0022377E67EFF34DAAAD0F812153593D01000000C867C6F2085D3850BF1F50275945CFEA90297C51D537E8C443B5F34050B325E0

How can I effectively size the target columns? Using Always `VARBINARY(MAX)` doesn't feel right!

I'm looking for something like:

- int => varbinary(32)
- varchar(x) => varbinary(Y)
- boolean => varbinary(10)
- DataTime => ...

Comment: Create some dummy data of various sizes and see how big it becomes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by @Joe Enos I tryed to encrypt several data types. This is the empiric result:

- integer: takes 52 bytes
- varchar(X): takes X+45 to X+65 bytes
- float: 68 bytes
- decimal(30,12): 68 bytes
- datetime: 68 bytes
- bit: 52 bytes